# Renaming districts in existing shapefile

Tags: gis, shapefile

Need to update names of towns and districts in a shapefile. Can this be done using QGIS 3? If yes, how? If not, what other methods can I use?

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the values in the attribute table once you have entered edit mode (left most button). Once you are finished remember to press the "save" button to write your changes back to the file.

[image]

Comment: My attribute table looks different. https://imgur.com/a/yMLCjhW